# How to connect to a Web Table from Azure data factory?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, linked-service

I am trying to connect to an external website from Azure data factory. For this I use the copy data activity. Also made a dataset and linked service to connect to the table on the external website. When I press the 'preview data' button on the dataset tab it shows me the data I want. However when I test the connection with the linked service it fails (2). Also when I run the pipeline that contains the copy data activity it fails and raises a badrequest, probably due to the connection with the linked service that fails (3).

**(1):**

[image]

**(2):**

[image]
**(3):**

[image]

How to make sure the connection with the linked service is successful? Can I adjust the timeout setting of the source dataset in Adf?

Comment: What is the timeout value given in the ADF pipeline?